# What are the first 4 bytes of a std::vector?

Tags: c++, vector

I would like to manually read the values, number of values, and capacity allotted to the vector.

From reading [this](https://frogatto.com/2009/11/17/how-cs-vector-works-the-gritty-details/), I believed that a std::vector could be manually accessed via the following struct

```
struct _vector{
    DWORD* begin;
    DWORD* end;
    DWORD* tail;
};
```

and that I could access the first value in the vector by doing the following.

```
_vector *vec = (_vector*)vectorAddress;
DWORD first_value = vec->begin[0];
```

However instead I found that this is not the case.  I needed to add another 4 byte value at the top of the struct in order to properly do access addresses for begin, end, and tail.  Below is the working version of what I would like to do.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
#include <vector>

std::vector<DWORD> vectorData;

void readVector(DWORD vectorAddress){
    struct _vector{
        DWORD* WHATISTHIS;
        DWORD* begin;
        DWORD* end;
        DWORD* tail;
    };

    _vector* vec = (_vector*)vectorAddress;

    DWORD count = ((DWORD)vec->end - (DWORD)vec->begin) / sizeof(DWORD);
    DWORD capacity = ((DWORD)vec->tail - (DWORD)vec->begin) / sizeof(DWORD);

    printf("Vector has %d items and %d capacity\n", count, capacity);

    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
        printf("\tValue at %d is 0x%x\n", i, vec->begin[i]);
}


int main(void){
    vectorData.reserve(3);
    vectorData.push_back(0x123456);
    vectorData.push_back(0x654321);

    while (true){
        readVector((DWORD)&vectorData);
        system("pause");
    }
}
```

Output of program:

```
Vector has 2 items and 3 capacity
        Value at 0 is 0x123456
        Value at 1 is 0x654321
Press any key to continue . . .
```

Given this what does the first 4 bytes of my _vector struct actually represent?

Comment: No, the article is explaining a possible implementation of `std::vector` (actually from a quick look I think only the standard-demanded interface). In no way is the layout guaranteed and you are certainly not allowed to just reinterpret it into some custom structure. Whatever result you are getting this way it is just undefined behavior.

Comment: `vector`'s internals are implementation specific. The "fields" you believe `vector` has are just accessor functions which are mandated by the standard. If you *absolutely* need low-level access, use [`vector::data()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/data/). Its only other state variables are given by `size()` and `capacity()`.

Comment: The only way to know is to look at the source code for your implementation.  All the standard guarantees is the interface and complexity, the actual implementation is left to the library implementor.

Comment: I see, thank you all for your input on the issue.